# How to align by column data like this?

Tags: mysql

Now I am designing comment function that can reply once to each very-top comment.

So, I want to align db records like

```
id| p     id| p
------    ------
1 | 0     1 | 0

2 | 0     5 | 1

3 | 0     6 | 1

4 | 0  => 2 | 0

5 | 1     7 | 2

6 | 1     3 | 0

7 | 2     4 | 0
```

I mean, if `p` indicates `id` value, the record should be located under `id` value record.

(envirenment is mysql)

Comment: I do not like this design. Why do not you add a `parent` column, and put the original comment id there?

Comment: What is parent column??

Comment: A column, named `parent` or `parentId` it could be `parent_comment_id`, you choose. The comments have `0` `parentId` by default, when somebody replies to it, store the original comment id as parent id in this cell.

Comment: Yeah, c2 column is only used for that purpose (What you named `parentId`). Value of each records (a,b,c ... etc) is actually numeric value. In short, c1 is `auto_increment unsigned int` column and c2 is used for what you named `parentId`.

Comment: sorry for confusing. I edit my question.

Comment: I solved this problem using controller logic. Thank you for help